# How to calculate the distance between a test object and all training objects

Tags: r

How to calculate the distance between a test object and all training objects.

Then, repeating this with other test objects and store them automatically.

The code I use for only one row of test set.

```
n <- matrix( )
  for (i in 1:nrow(wdbc_train)) {
      n[i]<-sum(abs(wdbc_train[i,]-wdbc_test[1,])^2)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using a subset of the Iris data.

```
wdbc_train <- iris[1:10, -5]
wdbc_test <- iris[8:15, -5]
```

For just to compare with one (the first) row of the test data

```
n <- sapply(1 : nrow(wdbc_train), function(i) sum(
       (wdbc_train[i, ] - wdbc_test[1, ])^2))
n
# [1] 0.03 0.18 0.17 0.25 0.05 0.49 0.18 0.00 0.62 0.11
```

Now repeat this for all the rows in the test data

```
mat <- sapply(1 : nrow(wdbc_test), function(y) 
  sapply(1 : nrow(wdbc_train), function(i) sum(
               (wdbc_train[i, ] - wdbc_test[y, ])^2)))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,] 0.03 0.85 0.22 0.14 0.14 0.35 0.99 0.78
# [2,] 0.18 0.26 0.03 0.75 0.21 0.02 0.46 1.85
# [3,] 0.17 0.19 0.10 0.78 0.14 0.07 0.25 1.86
# [4,] 0.25 0.09 0.10 1.00 0.14 0.07 0.27 2.34
# [5,] 0.05 0.85 0.28 0.18 0.12 0.41 0.95 0.84
# [6,] 0.49 2.13 1.02 0.12 0.66 1.35 2.47 0.46
# [7,] 0.18 0.30 0.23 0.75 0.09 0.24 0.38 1.85
# [8,] 0.00 0.62 0.11 0.25 0.05 0.22 0.82 1.09
# [9,] 0.62 0.00 0.31 1.65 0.45 0.18 0.12 3.21
# [10,] 0.11 0.31 0.00 0.62 0.12 0.03 0.53 1.72
```

You don't need `abs` function after taking `^2`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now suppose I want to find the 1NN (nearest neighbor) without built function in r, how should that work?

Comment: I guess then you can find which rows (`wdbc_train`) for a given column from `wdbd_test` are less than to a given threshold.  They would be some neighbours of that observation. I, however, have not looked into how 1NN is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two matrices, you could build a Euclidean distance matrix like so (I am going to assume the data is actually in the columns of both matrices, but it should be easy enough to edit for any configuration or distance metric):

```
output.matrix <- do.call(cbind,lapply(1:ncol(wdbc_train),function(i) {
    sapply(1:ncol(wdbc_test),function(j) sum((wdbc_test[,j]-wdbc_train[,i])^2))
}))
```

This will generate a matrix whose columns are each sample in the wdbc_train and the corresponding distance metric for each of the wdbc_test columns in the rows.

Comment: It does not work. I got 'There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)'